# ASP.NET: Bind HyperLinkColumn to more than one field

Tags: asp.net

Using ASP.NET and the DataGrid, how do I bind a HyperLinkColumn to more than one field?

```
    Dim detail As New HyperLinkColumn
    With detail
        .Text = "View Details"
        .HeaderText = ""
        .NavigateUrl = "\TeamDetail.aspx?Account={0}&Broker={1}"
        .DataNavigateUrlField = "AccountKey, BrokerNumberKey"
    End With
```

I was hoping for an data-binding event on HyperLinkColumn but no such luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a TemplateColumn. This will give you named controls you can work with in the ItemDataBound event.

ASP

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="LinkColumn" NavigateUrl="" Text="View Details"></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

VB

```
Private Sub ReportGrid_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles ReportGrid.ItemDataBound
    Const target = "/TeamsDetail.aspx?Account={0}&Broker={1)        Select Case e.Item.ItemType
        Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem
            Dim ctrl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("LinkColumn"), HyperLink)
            Dim row = CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
            If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then

                Dim accountKey = CInt(row("PrincipalAccountKey"))
                Dim brokerNumberKey = CInt(row("BrokerNumberKey"))
                ctrl.NavigateUrl = String.Format(target, accountKey, brokerNumberKey)
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```